# unable to correctly login to UI

Tags: keycloak

I'm completely new to keycloak trying to walk through [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak). I download keycloak-22.0.3, ran it locally using `bin/kc.sh start-dev`. I login into admin console, create new user, add credentials. Then I log-out and try to log in using new user (I tried it both in master and other realm). Doing so, I successfully log into UI, but the ui says it cannot load correctly:

[image]

Investigating the network traffic, the call to admin realm, say GET to `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/master/localization/en` return 403.

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version? The one you are running here is a major behind.

Comment: almost the same with keycloak-23.0.4; newer version just makes different rest calls which ends up with 403. Visually completely the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your new user doesn't have the right permissions to view or manage things in the admin console. You can find out how to assign roles [in the documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#assigning-permissions-using-roles-and-groups).

Comment: thanks. one more question: if I create new user, by default it's created with temporary password, which shall be updated within first 'usage'. Considering having access to this console is optional; where the user will update it's password? Sorry for beginner question, I will try to read more into manual next time before asking questions.

Comment: It's still possible to trigger the 'reset password' flow, this happens when the user signs into their account through the login, which is separate from the administration console.